# how to run can_open_motor node CanDriveHarmonica?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to run it, but there is no executable file. rosmake does not do anything cause of the file ROS_NOBUILD in different dependencies. And even if I deleate this one, in the CMakeLists.txt file is a line like: `rosbuild_add_executable(CanDriveHarmonica common/src/CanDriveHarmonica.cpp)`
missing.

I just downloaded the stack cob_driver and with it the can_open_motor, but nothing works. Any ideas how to solve the problems and run it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69535/how-to-run-can_open_motor-node-candriveharmonica?/) by [DIDI](https://answers.ros.org/users/4231/didi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The cob_driver stack is specific for Care-O-bot hardware and will probably not work without modifications on different hardware. Which hardware are you working on?

---

Originally posted by [weisshardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1163/weisshardt/) with karma: 106 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DIDI](https://answers.ros.org/users/4231/didi/) on 2013-07-29**:
I thought I can run CanDriveHarmonica to see the messages sent by the node to the Elmo Motion Control Harmonica. The aim is to reconstruct a realy old robot for ROS and I wanted the information which CAN messages are needed to be sent to Harmonica in order to initialise and steer it.